# How to put a link to facebook page's wall in a page tab app's iFrame?

Tags: facebook, iframe, hyperlink, facebook-wall

I had make a simple app into a facebook page and I just want to put a link to go back to the wall of the same page.

I tried with `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page_name?sk=wall">View the wall</a>` but it doesn't work(nothing happens).

Thanks fort he help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the link must be like this :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page_name?sk=wall" target="_top">View the wall</a>
```